# PIL ImageTK on Raspberry PI

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I tried to install ImageTk for Python3 on Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil
sudo apt-get install python3-imaging-tk
```

and:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-pil
E: Unable to locate package python3-imaging-tk
```

I search on the net but nothing. Whats the problem? How I fix this?

Note: I already updated the apt-get

Comment: I don't have a pi, but usually I install pillow with pip: `pip install pillow`. Does that work on your system?

Comment: @MichielOvertoom I found the problem, i have installed PIL, but he is outdated and doesnt work, and when i try to install pillow, python uses PIL, not Pillow. For resolve i removed PIL and Pillow and do: pip install pillow

Comment: In that case, I suggest you write your solution as the answer to this question topic, so that other people with the same problem can benefit from it ;-)  I'm glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I have installed PIL, but he is outdated and doesn't work, and when I try to install pillow, python uses PIL, not Pillow. For resolve I removed PIL and Pillow and do: pip install pillow

If you have the same problem, you have to unistall PIL and Pillow and install Pillow again. This works fine.